# Spring kafka - Example for using Non-blocking delayed retries with Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I would like to use spring kafka 2.7's new non-blocking delayed retries feature(https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic) within a kafka streams application, is there an example of this somewhere?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't ask the same question in multiple places; it is a waste of our time and yours. I already answered you on GitHub.

> There is no support for non-blocking retries with Kafka Streams - Spring for Apache Kafka support for Kafka Streams is limited to the factory bean for setting up the stream the Spring way, as well as providing a couple of transformers.

> Spring is not involved at runtime at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and am sorry for posting this question twice as well, did not realize you already answered won't do that again.